# Extracting data from a DataTable in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've been experimenting with Flutter DataTables and everything works fine displaying a table.

However, I'm also looking to allow users to edit the table. I'm populating the table with textfields but am at a complete loss as to how to get tabular data back out of the table. Getting individual cell values isn't a problem, it's trying to get its row and column positioning that I'm unable to do.

Any suggestions?